# Write regex that finds single-l words to double-l words

Tags: regex, firefox

I want to make a regex that convert British English to American English. One part of this is converting words like "instalment" to "installment". I currently have this one

```
\b([A-Za-z]*)l(?<!ll)(ful|ment)
```

and it works great, but just in Chrome; it crashes on Firefox due to the negative lookbehind. I need the lookbehind, though, to prevent "installment" from becoming "installlment".

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
/\b(?![A-Za-z]*ll(?:ful|ment)\b)([A-Za-z]*)l(ful|ment)\b/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZIJJjA/1).

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary (start of the word)
- `(?![A-Za-z]*ll(?:ful|ment)\b)` - no 0+ letters, `ll`, and `ful` or `ment` at the end of the word
- `([A-Za-z]*)` - Group 1: 0+ ASCII letters
- `l` - a `l`
- `(ful|ment)` - `ful` or `ment`
- `\b` - end of the word.